# Replacing an existing excel filename with another filename including timestamp in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to add timestamp to an existing excel file name, however, not able to beccause my code gives the following error:

---

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-c1bfbce8e566> in <module>
----> 1 os.rename(r'\dbg.ADS.DB.com\MAD-FSU\BoS_Data_Validations\Validation Engine\GTRNRE\GTRNRE_Validation_Report.xlsx',r'\dbg.ADS.DB.com\MAD-FSU\BoS_Data_Validations\Validation Engine\GTRNRE\GTRNRE_Validation_Report_'+TSExcel+'.xlsx')

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\dbg.ADS.DB.com\\MAD-FSU\\BoS_Data_Validations\\Validation Engine\\GTRNRE\\GTRNRE_Validation_Report.xlsx' -> '\\dbg.ADS.DB.com\\MAD-FSU\\BoS_Data_Validations\\Validation Engine\\GTRNRE\\GTRNRE_Validation_Report_20230710-16:27:57.xlsx'
```

Can someone please suggest what the issue is? I am new to phython and not sure how to resolve this - tried almost everything my understanding permits!

```
timestamp = pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime(2021, 10, 10))
res = timestamp.today()
def numConcat(num1, num2):
        # Convert both the numbers to strings
        num1 = str(num1)
        num2 = str(num2)
        # Concatenate the strings
        num1 += num2
        return int(num1)
a = res.year
b = res.strftime("%m")
CurrDate=numConcat(a, b)
CurrDate

TSExcel = str(a) + res.strftime('%m%d-%H:%M:%S')

import os

os.rename(r'\dbg.ADS.DB.com\MAD-FSU\BoS_Data_Validations\Validation Engine\GTRNRE\GTRNRE_Validation_Report.xlsx',r'\dbg.ADS.DB.com\MAD-FSU\BoS_Data_Validations\Validation Engine\GTRNRE\GTRNRE_Validation_Report_'+TSExcel+'.xlsx')
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly the problem: the path that you are passing is incorrect. You have to troubleshoot that and put the correct path for it to get to the file

Comment: Did you check that the file locations you are using are correct?

Comment: FileNotFoundError is self-explanatory

Comment: A filename starting with one backslash on Windows is relative to the root folder of the drive of the current working directory.

Comment: Is that a network share? You need two backslashes on the front `r'\\dbg.ADS.DB.com\MAD-FSU\..."`

Comment: It's the correct directory. And I am getting the below error now - 

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '\\\\dbg.ADS.DB.com\\MAD-FSU\\BoS_Data_Validations\\Validation Engine\\GTRNRE\\GTRNRE_Validation_Report.xlsx' -> '\\\\dbg.ADS.DB.com\\MAD-FSU\\BoS_Data_Validations\\Validation Engine\\GTRNRE\\GTRNRE_Validation_Report_20230710-16:27:57.xlsx'

Comment: Yes, it's a network share. And I have amended the syntax with two back slashes:
os.rename(r'\\dbg.ADS.DB.com\MAD-FSU\BoS_Data_Validations\Validation Engine\GTRNRE\GTRNRE_Validation_Report.xlsx',r'\\dbg.ADS.DB.com\MAD-FSU\BoS_Data_Validations\Validation Engine\GTRNRE\GTRNRE_Validation_Report_'+TSExcel+'.xlsx')

Comment: If I remember correctly, Windows forbids colons in file and directory names.

Comment: I haven't used windows in awhile and don't remember the tools, but from the command line you could `ping dbg.ADS.DB.com` to see if its reachable. Or even do a `dir the path` to read it.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher - it worked! I have removed the colons!